# Google is rolling out single parenting instead of multiple parenting for files and folders in GDRIVE. What is the advantage? I only see inconvenients

Tags: google-drive-api, flysystem-google-drive

Multiple parenting advantages instead of single parenting:

- You can see all the parents in the info bars
- When you grant access to the file you do it one time whereas with single parenting you have give acces to the file and each shortcut
- If you change the name of the file the name change in each location where it is saved where as by single parenting you have to update all the shorcutsname manually

  shortcuts to folder can not be expanded in the left pane

  shortcuts are not sychronised to google file stream

Because I am probably not seeing the advantages of single parenting. I can not understand how Google can switch multiple parenting to single parenting. Does anybody can give what are the advantages of single parenting?

Comment: This is an opinion based question. This is not the forum for such questions, SO is about programming questions. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: not only as the consequences for programming are heavy because it changes completely the concept. I was hoping that someone would tell me for example: the advantages are in programming to avoid this .... or this ...

Comment: you can ask software architecture or design questions in https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/, Check [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124869)